# Error 1009, when doing GET request on local network

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wifi, hotspot

URLSession Error -1009 on local server

I need to fetch data from a hardware device using HTTPS protocol. The IP address of the device is **192.168.4.1**, when I'm connected to the device using it is hotspot on my pc, then I'm calling GET request https://192.168.4.1/scanlist on Postman and it's return the JSON data in response. But when I connect device hotspot with iPhone and I'm trying same GET request on iPhone, I'm getting an URLSession Error -1009.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://192.168.4.1/scanlist") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])
            print(jsonResponse) //Response result
            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [ScanList] else {
                return
            }
            for dic in jsonArray{
                self.ssidListArr.append(dic)
            }
            if self.ssidListArr.count > 0{
                self.popUpView.isHidden = false
                // populate tableview
            }
        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

'''

Error I'm getting :

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.

My info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <key>192.168.4.1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!-- Optional: Specify minimum TLS version -->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: In your code, you list the IP address as `192.168.4.2`, is it .2 or .1?

Comment: @JacobDyer In the code IP address is ending with .1